# Set Associative Cache: Calculating Index

Tags: java, caching

I am trying to implement a 2-way set associative cache simulating using LRU in Java, but I am having trouble understanding which set to insert an address into.

I am given

Address: `400000` (A Read)

Cache Line Size: `8 bytes`

Total Number of Cache Lines: `8192`

Using this information, I am able to get:

`1024` lines (8192 / 8)

`512` sets (1024 / 2)

At this point I am unsure how to get the index regarding where to put Address 400000 in a set or even calculating which set to put it into.

Implementation wise, I am planning on using an array of objects, with each object containing 2 linked-lists (for LRU) since this is a 2-way set associative cache.